# Masstransit message consumption order

Tags: publish-subscribe, servicebus, masstransit

I have a publishing endpoint 'P' and two consumers 'A', 'B'.
When 'P' publish messages '1' '2' '3', I expect that consumers would consume messages with the order of '123'. But in reality consumption order maybe '132', '312' and so forth.
I have configured the settings related to concurrency but it doesn't work
[concurrency settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F935h.png)

**Question**: Is there a configuration that could prevent 'B' from taking message until 'A' consumes message successfully ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no guarantee regarding processing messages in order, and should be avoided at all costs.

Messages in the queue is FIFO but when you have multiple consumers with pre-fetch setup, each consumer A and B will pull x messages off the queue, and process them depending on how long it takes it, consumer A could go back for more message before consumer B is done, and process messages out of order which is common situation.

Message retries could also cause messages to be processed out of order.

Saying this, if you do required this, using a single consumer set with a concurrency limit of 1 would process messages in order, at the cost of throughput.

Comment: Thanks for reply. As far as I set pre-fetch to 0, A still could fetch message before B completes consumption. Is this means that masstransit or rabbitmq doesn't support this kind of 'block' ?

Comment: nothing with queues and distributed consumers would support it, if order is really important then you could look at stream processing (apache kafka)

Comment: Why is ordered message processing so important?

Comment: I'm doing a cross IDC memory sync work, so the consumption order of receiving endpoint should be the same with publishing endpoint.

Comment: I decided to use single consumer to process messages, which could also solve retry problems and failover scenario. Thanks a lot :)